# Unable to scroll element in Appium 1.20

Tags: appium

I'm using *Appium 1.20*. I'm trying to find a way to scroll to an element.

```
public static void scrollToElement(WebElement e) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = driver;
    HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
    scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
    scrollObject.put("name", e.getId()); // <-- there is no getId for WebElement.
    js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `getId()` for `WebElement`.

How do you scroll to an element in *Appium 2*?

Comment: May I know your targeted platform where you are unable to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

If it is android, you can use

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"**/Put some text of scroll screen/**\").instance(0))")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to scroll to an element in Appium 2:

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Element name']");

Point point = element.getLocation();
int startX = (int) (point.getX() * 0.5);
int endX = (int) (point.getX() * 0.5);
int startY = (int) (point.getY() * 0.5);
int endY = (int) (point.getY() * 0.8);

TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.press(startX, startY).waitAction().moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

You can also use the scrollIntoView method as below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```